# Copy ElasticSearch Index: dump ended with error (set phase)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

versiontarget cluster - 6.2.4
version source cluster - 5.4.1
OS CentOs 7
Did install yum install elasticdump on server source cluster,

Did try execute command

```
elasticdump --input=http://server01:9200/kafka-broker-2017.07 --output=http://server02:9200/kafka-broker-2017.07 --type=mapping
```

other variant

```
elasticdump --input=http://server01:9200/kafka-broker-2017.07 --output=http://server02:9200/kafka-broker-2017.07 --type=data
```

after did return error:

1. Mon, 06 Aug 2018 20:18:09 GMT | starting dump
   Mon, 06 Aug 2018 20:18:09 GMT | got 1 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 0)
   Mon, 06 Aug 2018 20:18:09 GMT | Error Emitted => "Content-Type header [] is not supported"
   Mon, 06 Aug 2018 20:18:09 GMT | Total Writes: 0
   Mon, 06 Aug 2018 20:18:09 GMT | dump ended with error (set phase)  => Content-Type header [] is not supported

2.

```
Mon, 06 Aug 2018 20:19:49 GMT | starting dump
Mon, 06 Aug 2018 20:19:49 GMT | Error Emitted => {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"The field [fields] is no longer supported, please use [stored_fields] to retrieve stored fields or _source filtering if the field is not stored","line":1,"col":36}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"The field [fields] is no longer supported, please use [stored_fields] to retrieve stored fields or _source filtering if the field is not stored","line":1,"col":36},"status":400}
Mon, 06 Aug 2018 20:19:49 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Mon, 06 Aug 2018 20:19:49 GMT | dump ended with error (get phase) => Error: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"The field [fields] is no longer supported, please use [stored_fields] to retrieve stored fields or _source filtering if the field is not stored","line":1,"col":36}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"The field [fields] is no longer supported, please use [stored_fields] to retrieve stored fields or _source filtering if the field is not stored","line":1,"col":36},"status":400}
```

If did get list indexis

curl -XGET http://server01:9200/_cat/indices | grep kafka-broker

yellow open kafka-broker-2017.07     iX966c6zRQOSjnZdm9zEEB 5 1    201577      0  28.8mb  20.5mb

How solve this problem?

p.s.

```
elasticdump --input=http://server01:9200/iX966c6zRQOSjnZdm9zEEB --output=http://server02:9200/iX966c6zRQOSjnZdm9zEEB --type=data
```

did return

```
Mon, 06 Aug 2018 20:30:58 GMT | starting dump
Mon, 06 Aug 2018 20:30:58 GMT | Error Emitted => {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"The field [fields] is no longer supported, please use [stored_fields] to retrieve stored fields or _source filtering if the field is not stored","line":1,"col":36}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"The field [fields] is no longer supported, please use [stored_fields] to retrieve stored fields or _source filtering if the field is not stored","line":1,"col":36},"status":400}
Mon, 06 Aug 2018 20:30:58 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Mon, 06 Aug 2018 20:30:58 GMT | dump ended with error (get phase) => Error: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"The field [fields] is no longer supported, please use [stored_fields] to retrieve stored fields or _source filtering if the field is not stored","line":1,"col":36}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"The field [fields] is no longer supported, please use [stored_fields] to retrieve stored fields or _source filtering if the field is not stored","line":1,"col":36},"status":400}
```

Comment: Why not simply using [remote reindexing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote)?

Comment: did use your variant, problem resolved